# Dual-booted computer switches OS when asleep

Tags: windows, multi-boot, linux-mint, sleep, hibernate

I have a computer set up to dual boot Windows 10 and Linux Mint. When I leave the computer sitting and it goes to sleep under Windows, I find that it will wake back up suddenly booted in the linux partition.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Update: Two new interesting things:

1. It has not done in a couple of days, maybe something is keeping it awake.
2. I noticed that when I then shut down linux and go back to boot up windows, it is not coming back from hibernation, rather, it is loading as if I completly shut down windows.

Comment: Regarding 2: I'm not sure there is any documentation on how Windows really checks if it is in hibernation or not. It is most likely only known by Microsoft.. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix #1: Set Windows as your default boot option

Quick fix #2: Turn off hibernation

When Windows hibernates, it saves the current system state in a file called `hiberfile.sys` and completely shuts down. When you then boot your computer, it will restore the system state from this file.

BUT since you have Linux installed, the boot loader (`grub`, most likely) have no idea of this fact, and will start the default OS. If you change the default to Windows, the Windows boot loader should check for that file and resume the computer as you would expect.

Comment: I Would like to have windows as default boot, but how do I set it to boot to windows automatically, but still have a way to switch to Linux.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/485726/set-the-grub-default-os-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-14-04 should do the trick

Comment: I just added some new details, do you mind looking at it. I am going to look at that link, but life has been in the way.

Comment: Option 3 would be to make GRUB remember the last-used boot option.

Comment: @grawity I wasn't aware of that option :)